# Deled special tgas inckeditor

Tags: ckeditor

I have this line in code into a longtext field in ckeditor:

```
 <div style="width:100%"> <canvas id="canvas3"></canvas></div>
```

but when I save then delete and replace by:

```
<div style="width:100%">&nbsp;</div>
```

so delete all:  I use to show graphics. Any idea to solved it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `config.extraAllowedContent = 'canvas[*]{*}(*)';` inside your `config.js`. Basically none of existing plugins has reported `canvas` element to Advanced Content Filter (ACF) thus they get removed. This filter lets you decide what tags, attributes, styles and classes can be used inside the editor.

Once you add this, please simply switch to source mode. If `canvas` are there it means CKEditor is fixed and it no longer removes that tag. If the tag, despite being in editor, still isn't saved in your data base, please check your server-side code for potential HTML filters.

If you wish learn more about ACF, please see:

- https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_acf.html
- https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter.html
- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_disallowed_content.html
- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-allowedContent
- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-extraAllowedContent
- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-disallowedContent
- https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_filter.html#method-addTransformations